# background-image next to text doesn't woking

Tags: html, css

I have the following CSS code:

```
#left .gcontent { display: block; margin-bottom: 20px; border-radius:5px; width:300px; }
#left .gcontent .head { background: #589fc6; border: 1px solid #3e82a7; padding-right: 8px; border-top-left-radius:5px; border-top-right-radius:5px; }
#left .gcontent .head h1 { color: #fafcfd; font-weight: bold; font-size: 1.1em; padding:0; margin:0; text-decoration:none; }
#left .gcontent .boxy { border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px; border: 1px solid #ccc; border-top: 0px; padding: 10px 8px; background: #f9f9f9; }
#left .gcontent .boxy span { font-size: 1.2em; display: block; margin-top: 7px; background-image:url(../images/main/left-arrow.png); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:15px 15px; clear:right;} 
#left .gcontent .boxy p {line-height:25px; }
```

And this HTML source

```
<div class="gcontent">
    <div class="head">
        <h1>TITLE </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="boxy">
        SOME TEXT
        <span>TEXTY TEXT</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that the "left-arrow" background image (in the span) is in the left, and not very close to the text.

My question is how can I fix this so the picture will be realy next to the text?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: I can't, sorry (beacuse there is no option to see there the inage, so it will be useless)..

Comment: Change your link to use the full URL to the image when using jsFiddle.

Comment: add a width to `#left .gcontent .boxy` so that you make it smaller or increase the `left` or `right padding`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can position a background image with background-position:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp

```
#left .gcontent .boxy span
{
    font-size: 1.2em;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 7px;
    background-image: url('left-arrow.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 15px 15px;
    clear: right;
    background-position: left;
    background-position: 200px 0px;
 }
```

Comment: I've added the CSS. For me its working. (Chromium 20)
And here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c48x4/1/

Comment: Thank you! That is realy better, but the problem is that the text near the arrow is dynamic, so the arrow position can't be static..

Comment: Then have a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c48x4/2/
The background-image has to be aligned to some container which has the width of the text.

Comment: Your welcome, oh and by the way, the display: inline now is actually dispensable because span is an inline element anyways.